# Why does math.floor() round up numbers after 15 decimal places in python?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding, floor, math-functions

I am trying to calculate the floor value of certain numbers.

It works fine when I run this: `math.floor(9.999999999999999)` .
I get the output as `9` .  This number has 15 decimal places.

However, `math.floor()` seems to fail after 15 decimal places.

When I run this: `math.floor(9.9999999999999999)` , I get the output as `10` .  This number has 16 decimal places.

I want to understand why `math.floor()` is rounding up the number after 15 decimal places.

**NOTE** :

Somehow, adding `1` after the 15th decimal place also works correctly.

Input : `math.floor(9.9999999999999991111)`

Output : `9`

However, any other number besides `1` , and the number gets rounded up.

Input : `math.floor(9.9999999999999992)`

Output : `10`

I would like to understand the reason for this unusual behavior in python.

Comment: To add on to mousetail's linked question, you can try to enter the values you listed as-is into a terminal. You will see that the return from the terminal is different from the input value.

Comment: Forget about `floor`, the point is that floating point numbers don't have enough precision for more than ~17 decimal digits. If you print `9.9999999999999999` you'll discover that it's already 10.0 (and `9.9999999999999999 == 10.0` evaluates to `true`), as it's "snapped" to the nearest representable number on parsing.